# xfce: Prevent multiple instances of apps

Tags: unity, launcher, xfce

What is really annoying in Ubuntu is that when some apps which don't need multiple instances such as 'appearance settings', a web browser, terminal window are loaded again when they are aready launched. For a browser or terminal I can still understand, although such apps have a 'new window' option. But for settings apps, multiple instances of e.g. 'Appearence' or 'Keyboard settings' are completely useless.

How do I prevent that the launcher launches an app (e.g. Firefox) again when it is already launched ?

I tried a shellscript called launch.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! pgrep $1 >/dev/null; then 
    "$2" &
fi
```

In the xfce launcher for Firefox I set

`launch.sh firefox /usr/bin/firefox`

which does work (firefox is not launched when it is areay open), but for `xfce4-appearance-settings` it does not work, because `pgrep xfce4-appearance-settings` returns nothing while xfce4-appearance-settings is opened.

In macOS it works properly: such apps are launched only once and when clicking again on the app icon, it moves to the foreground rather than starting a new obsolete instance.

How can this be realized in Ubuntu ?

Comment: It might help if you clarify your tags; you've tagged it's about Xfce but also **not** about Xfce instead about the Unity desktop.  You can only use Unity **or** Xfce desktop and not both at the same time, so which are you using? or how does your question relate to Unity?, and what release are you asking about.

Comment: This applies to Unity as well, it is a Ubuntu issue, particularly 22.04 and 20.04.

Comment: This wmctrl works great !

Answer (score 1):

It is the application itself that controls that behavior.

A command, e.g. for firefox, that switches to a running window, and only launches the program if it is not running, looks like:

```
wmctrl -x -a firefox || firefox
```

In bash, the command separator `||` means "OR". The first command, `wmctrl`, attempts to switch to a window of WM_CLASS "firefox". If that fails, `firefox` is executed.

The first instance `firefox` refers to the WM_CLASS of a firefox window. You can see the WM_CLASS of running windows in the output of `wmctrl -lx`.

To use this for a shortcut key, or in a .desktop launcher, use following command:

```
sh -c "wmctrl -x -a firefox || firefox"
```